# Having issue centering a col without centering other content in parent row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two col in a row and would like to center the first col (a photo), but not the second col and child content. It's for a responsive layout when viewing on a small device. However, in order to do so, I would have to use the text-center class on the parent row but I don't want content of the 2nd col centered.

Here is a photo of how the layout looks both at full screen and on smaller screen. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW0Rq.jpg

Any ideas on a workaround?

```css
.blog-topics {
  max-width: 180px;
  max-height: 180px;
}

.blog-post {
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.blog-box {
  max-width: 700px;
}

.blog-post-topic {
  color: #17a2b8;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.blog-post-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.blog-post-excerpt {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #686868;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 540px) {
  .btn-blog {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row p-3">
  <div class="col border">
    <h3 class="text-center">Recent Posts</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <img src="img/guy.jpg" alt="topic" class="blog-post">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md blog-box">
        <p class="blog-post-topic">Privary & Security</p>
        <p class="blog-post-title">Guarding Against Computer Malware</p>
        <p class="blog-post-excerpt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-blog mb-4">Read More</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with Bootstrap classes. Instead of col-auto on all breakpoints (which was the root of the problem), only use col-auto on a higher breakpoint (I chose col-md-auto).  That way when stacked, the image column takes the full available width and allows us to center the image within.

```
<div class="row p-3">
        <div class="col border">
            <h3 class="text-center">Recent Posts</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-auto d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="topic" class="blog-post">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md blog-box">
                    <p class="blog-post-topic">Privary & Security</p>
                    <p class="blog-post-title">Guarding Against Computer Malware</p>
                    <p class="blog-post-excerpt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-blog mb-4">Read More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to set `margin: 0 auto` on the parent `.col-auto`:

```css
.blog-topics {
  max-width: 180px;
  max-height: 180px;
}

.blog-post {
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.blog-box {
  max-width: 700px;
}

.blog-post-topic {
  color: #17a2b8;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.blog-post-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.blog-post-excerpt {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #686868;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.col-auto {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (max-width: 540px) {
  .btn-blog {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="row p-3">
  <div class="col border">
    <h3 class="text-center">Recent Posts</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/100" alt="topic" class="blog-post">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md blog-box">
        <p class="blog-post-topic">Privary & Security</p>
        <p class="blog-post-title">Guarding Against Computer Malware</p>
        <p class="blog-post-excerpt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-blog mb-4">Read More</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```